# PHP foreach issue with empty fields

Tags: php, foreach

I have a big form

This form is processed by a PHP file called by a serialize jQuery function

```
foreach($_GET['claimant'] as $k=>$v) {
$insClaim = "INSERT INTO `cR_Claimants` (`memberID`, `ParentSubmission`, `Name`, `DOB`, `Company`, `Email`, `MainPhone`, `OtherPhone`, `MobilePhone`, `OwnershipPercentage`, `Address`, `ZIPcode`, `Country`) VALUES ('".$memberID."', '".$refNumb."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['name'])."', '".$v['DOB']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['company'])."', '".$v['email']."', '".$v['mainPhone']."', '".$v['alternatePhone']."', '".$v['mobilePhone']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['percentage'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['address'])."', '".$v['ZIP']."', '".$v['country']."')";
$resultinsClaim=mysql_query($insClaim) or die("Error insert Claimants: ".mysql_error());
}
```

The problem is that `$_GET['claimant']` in certain cases can be empty. I mean that the relative field has not been entered at all.

When this happens obviously the Insert should not run when that specific `$_GET['claimant']` is empty.

I tried the two following solutions, but they do not work, the Insert runs anyway, putting in my DB empty strings.

Please help.

```
foreach($_GET['claimant'] as $k=>$v) {
if($_GET['claimant'] != "") {
$insClaim = "INSERT INTO `cR_Claimants` (`memberID`, `ParentSubmission`, `Name`, `DOB`, `Company`, `Email`, `MainPhone`, `OtherPhone`, `MobilePhone`, `OwnershipPercentage`, `Address`, `ZIPcode`, `Country`) VALUES ('".$memberID."', '".$refNumb."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['name'])."', '".$v['DOB']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['company'])."', '".$v['email']."', '".$v['mainPhone']."', '".$v['alternatePhone']."', '".$v['mobilePhone']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['percentage'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['address'])."', '".$v['ZIP']."', '".$v['country']."')";
$resultinsClaim=mysql_query($insClaim) or die("Error insert Claimants: ".mysql_error());
}
}
```

AND

```
foreach($_GET['claimant'] as $k=>$v) {
if(!empty($_GET['claimant'])) {
$insClaim = "INSERT INTO `cR_Claimants` (`memberID`, `ParentSubmission`, `Name`, `DOB`, `Company`, `Email`, `MainPhone`, `OtherPhone`, `MobilePhone`, `OwnershipPercentage`, `Address`, `ZIPcode`, `Country`) VALUES ('".$memberID."', '".$refNumb."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['name'])."', '".$v['DOB']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['company'])."', '".$v['email']."', '".$v['mainPhone']."', '".$v['alternatePhone']."', '".$v['mobilePhone']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['percentage'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($v['address'])."', '".$v['ZIP']."', '".$v['country']."')";
$resultinsClaim=mysql_query($insClaim) or die("Error insert Claimants: ".mysql_error());
}
}
```

Comment: You need to validate your data before adding it in your query. this is very bad practice

Comment: also is $_GET['claimant'] an array of data?

Comment: Can you do a print_r on the $_GET['claimant'] and post the results up?

Comment: of course all the answers below are wild guesses, because nobody knows the content of your get variable. do a print_r($_GET). and add the result to your question. then you will get some real help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $_GET['claimant'] is an array, you should ask for its length:

```
if (count($_GET['claimant']) > 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The check should be:

```
if(!empty($v)) {
    // Stuff here
}
```

This is assuming that the GET variable actually contains an array of arrays.

Most likely you don't need the foreach.

This code is also vulnerable to SQL injection, **all** parameters needs to be escaped before entered into a SQL query

Try this instead:

```
$vals = $_GET['claimant'];
if(!empty($vals)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `cR_Claimants` (`memberID`, `ParentSubmission`, `Name`, `DOB`, `Company`, `Email`, `MainPhone`, `OtherPhone`, `MobilePhone`, `OwnershipPercentage`, `Address`, `ZIPcode`, `Country`) VALUES ('".$memberID."', '".$refNumb."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['name'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['DOB'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['company'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['email'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['mainPhone'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['alternatePhone'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['mobilePhone'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['percentage'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['address'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['ZIP'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($vals['country'])."')";
    $resultinsClaim=mysql_query($insClaim) or die("Error insert Claimants: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: None of the above are working. $_GET['claimant'] is an array of values. My users have some inputs, some of those inputs are the same. Lets say they can write details for 1 or more Claimants. Each claimant has other fields as you see in the INsertion. But the users can even enter the details on only 1 Claimant, this is when all the other empty fields should checked and not considered in the loop.

Comment: Is `$_GET['claimant']` an array of values or an array of arrays of values?

You most likely need to perform any validation before the creation of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using a `foreach()` loop here...`_GET['claimant']` is probably not an array of values unless you have multiple fields on your form called `claimant[]`.

Just do this:

```
$claimant = $_GET['claimant'];
if( $claimant != ""){
    $insClaim = "YOUR REALLY LONG QUERY";
    // etc.
}
```

ALSO:  please, please, please use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all incoming request parameters.